# How to transfer dlls between projects

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I wrote a whole bunch of class libraries for silverlight.

I want another programming group to use them, but not to see my code.

What is the best way to distribute them so it is easy for them to use?

I thought at first that it would be as simple as copying over the class library dll.  What is confusing me now is how to deal with all the supporting dlls?  Both supporting custom dlls made by me and system dlls that need to be included for my class libraries to function

Comment: [ILMerge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569269) works great for bundling assemblies together; I only do "normal" .NET programming, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* simply a case of supplying your library DLLs and of *your own* supporting DLLs but you should also supply a list of any 3rd party DLLs & system DLLs that they reference (so that the developers can add them explicitly to their main projects).

Anything you miss will be listed as a link error so will be found/noticed quickly.

The only extra thing I would suggest is use a commercial naming pattern for your DLL like:
*companyname.area.subsystem.version.dll*